# Invalid cast from System.String to MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId while Deserialize Json String .Net

Tags: json, asp.net-core

I'm learning redis recently, and try to use key-value stringset the model into json string as value. I can serialize the model into json string success, but when I try to deserialize it back to model, an exception come out. If I don't want to change the type of Id to string, is there got other way to solve this problem? Thanks you.

Exception:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error converting value "5b5b4df5b8e2e208efb2c0da" to type 'MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId'. Path 'Id', line 1, position 64.'
InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId'.
```

Model:

```
public class TblUser
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Serialize:

```
public static string ObjToStr(Object obj)
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
}
```

Deserialize:

```
public static T StrToObj<T>(string str)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(str);
}
```